# How to change the executer of python in vscode?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I was trying to change the **executer** of **python** in **vscode**.
I have installed python3 in my system.However default executer of python in vscode is python.So i am getting error as 'python not found' whenever i try to run code. So how could  i change the executer to python3 in line no 4066?
[image]

I tried to change from user settings. I could change the interpreter there. However i didnt find any way to change the executer.
[image]

Comment: See in the bottom left there where it says Python 3.8, click that and use whichever python interpreter/version of Python 3.x you wish to use. Usually one will be recommended to you. In my experience you shouldn't have to mess around with that config file.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's default command **Code Runner** provides for Python Language.

As long as the execution scripts in terminal when you **run python file** is python3.8, **run code** should also use python3.8.

OR you can change the command directly:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "path/to/python3.8/python.exe -u",
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much! that worked !